# Heroku - failed to push some refs

Tags: python, heroku

I am getting this error- 'failed to push some refs'- as many others have, but not sure what specifically in my code is inducing the error.

I am simply trying to deploy an app through heroku.

Here is the terminal code:

```
(venv) (base) adam:dash adam$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 3.43 KiB | 702.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.10
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: Sqlite3 successfully installed.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting aiohttp==3.6.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2MB)
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.12 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/ad/00b090d23a222943eb0eda509720a404f531a439e803f6538f35136cae9e/alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to nba-proj-knox.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/nba-proj-knox.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/nba-proj-knox.git'
```

I do see this within the code:

```
remote:        Collecting anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9297955900f64ba30fd35257fbd20605/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

But still not sure how to fix this.

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
aiohttp==3.6.2
alabaster==0.7.12
anaconda-client==1.7.2
anaconda-navigator==1.9.7
anaconda-project==0.8.3
appnope==0.1.0
appscript==1.0.1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==2.2.5
astropy==3.2.1
async-timeout==3.0.1
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
Babel==2.7.0
backcall==0.1.0
backports.functools-lru-cache==1.6.1
backports.os==0.1.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
basemap==1.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bitarray==0.9.3
bkcharts==0.2
bleach==3.1.0
bokeh==1.2.0
boto==2.49.0
Bottleneck==1.2.1
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.6.16
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
cloudpickle==1.2.1
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.4.1
conda==4.7.12
conda-build==3.18.8
conda-package-handling==1.6.0
conda-verify==3.4.2
contextlib2==0.5.5
cryptography==2.7
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.29.12
cytoolz==0.10.0
dash==0.21.1
dash-core-components==0.23.0
dash-html-components==0.11.0
dash-renderer==0.13.0
dash-table==4.5.1
dask==2.1.0
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
df2gspread==1.0.4
distributed==2.1.0
docutils==0.14
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.1.0
filelock==3.0.12
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
future==0.18.2
gevent==1.4.0
glob2==0.7
gmpy2==2.0.8
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
google-auth==1.7.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
greenlet==0.4.15
gspread==3.1.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
h5py==2.9.0
heapdict==1.0.0
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.14.0
idna==2.8
imageio==2.5.0
imagesize==1.1.0
importlib-metadata==0.17
ipykernel==5.1.1
ipython==7.6.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.0
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jedi==0.13.3
Jinja2==2.10.1
joblib==0.13.2
json5==0.8.4
jsonschema==3.0.1
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.1
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-core==4.5.0
jupyter-server-proxy==1.2.0
jupyterlab==1.0.2
jupyterlab-dash==0.1.0a3
jupyterlab-server==1.0.0
keyring==18.0.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.1
libarchive-c==2.8
lief==0.9.0
llvmlite==0.29.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==4.3.4
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.0
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.0.12
mkl-random==1.0.2
mkl-service==2.0.2
mock==3.0.5
more-itertools==7.0.0
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack==0.6.1
multidict==4.7.3
multipledispatch==0.6.0
navigator-updater==0.2.1
nbconvert==5.5.0
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.3
nltk==3.4.4
nose==1.3.7
notebook==6.0.0
numba==0.44.1
numexpr==2.6.9
numpy==1.16.4
numpydoc==0.9.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
olefile==0.46
openpyxl==2.6.2
packaging==19.0
pandas==0.24.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.5.0
partd==1.0.0
path.py==12.0.1
pathlib2==2.3.4
patsy==0.5.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==6.1.0
pkginfo==1.5.0.1
plotly==4.4.1
pluggy==0.12.0
ply==3.11
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
psutil==5.6.3
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser==2.19
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.3
pyflakes==2.1.1
Pygments==2.4.2
pylint==2.3.1
pyodbc==4.0.26
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyparsing==2.4.0
pyproj==1.9.6
pyrsistent==0.14.11
pyshp==2.1.0
PySocks==1.7.0
pytest==5.0.1
pytest-arraydiff==0.3
pytest-astropy==0.5.0
pytest-doctestplus==0.3.0
pytest-openfiles==0.3.2
pytest-remotedata==0.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.1
PyWavelets==1.0.3
PyYAML==5.1.1
pyzmq==18.0.0
QtAwesome==0.5.7
qtconsole==4.5.1
QtPy==1.8.0
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
rope==0.14.0
rsa==4.0
ruamel-yaml==0.15.46
scikit-image==0.15.0
scikit-learn==0.21.2
scipy==1.3.0
seaborn==0.9.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
simpervisor==0.3
simplegeneric==0.8.1
simplejson==3.17.0
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
snowballstemmer==1.9.0
sortedcollections==1.1.2
sortedcontainers==2.1.0
soupsieve==1.8
Sphinx==2.1.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.3
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.1.2
spyder==3.3.6
spyder-kernels==0.5.1
SQLAlchemy==1.3.5
statsmodels==0.10.0
sympy==1.4
tables==3.5.2
tblib==1.4.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
toolz==0.10.0
tornado==6.0.3
tqdm==4.32.1
traitlets==4.3.2
unicodecsv==0.14.1
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.24.2
virtualenv==16.7.9
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.15.4
widgetsnbextension==3.5.0
wrapt==1.11.2
wurlitzer==1.0.2
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==1.1.8
xlwings==0.15.8
xlwt==1.3.0
yarl==1.4.2
zict==1.0.0
zipp==0.5.1
```

Comment: I believe this to be a typo in your requirements.txt file. The highest version of anaconda-client is 1.2.2 (https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/) and you have 1.7.2 Please re-attempt with anaconda-client=1.2.2

Comment: Also, that's a lot of packages. Does your project need each one of those?

Comment: @bernie thanks, there were definitely issues in the requirements.txt that I edited out